# How to format hour and minute in Chinese with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, time, localization

I need to display a time in Chinese format with PHP.

I already try to use strftime :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "zh_CN");
echo strftime("%a, %Y %B %d");
```

It's work for date and display : 二, 2013 十一月 05

but for time :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "zh_CN");
echo strftime("%H %M");
```

display : 14 30

But 2:30pm have to be displayed like : 下午2时30分 for zh_CN and 下午2時半 for zh_HK

Did you kwon a solution or a php library to do that ?

Thx

PS : a javascript solution on client side can be good also ;)

Comment: Why would `%H %M` be anything different as the output you got (`14 30`)? `%H` is two digit representation of the hour in 24-hour format `00 through 23`; and `%M` is similar.

Comment: @Glavić true, so strftime("%H %M") is not the good solution. It's the reason why I search another solution :)

Comment: Try `%I:%M %p` where `%p` will be translated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the exact output you want but this is normally a good job for the [intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension:

```
<?php

$locales = array(
    'en_US',
    'en_GB',
    'zh_CN',
    'zh_HK',
);

$date = new DateTime('14:30');
foreach($locales as $locale){
    $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter($locale, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
    echo $fmt->format($date) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

... prints:

```
2:30 PM
14:30
下午2:30
下午2:30
```

If you stick to [strftime](http://php.net/strftime) you'd have to use `%I` ("Two digit representation of the hour in 12-hour format") rather than `%H` ("Two digit representation of the hour in 24-hour format") together with `%p/%P` ("AM/PM"). There's also `%X` ("Preferred time representation based on locale, without the date").

If you don't really need to support many languages, writing your own date formatter would be a sensible alternative.

*As for JavaScript, I always see [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) recommended here but I haven't used it.*

Answer (score 0):

PHP gives inconsistent results when it comes to Chinese time support.

The solution which worked for me is to output the time ISO format and use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to get very close to the perfect solution to deal with internationalised time:

In php output your time to a `<span>`.

```
echo '<span date="'.date('c').'" moment-format="LT">'
    .date('h:n').'</span>';
```

where `date('c')` returns the ISO formatted date and `moment-format` defines the format moment.js should use to replace the ISO time

In Javascript you simply replace all the time formats :

```
    moment.lang('zh-cn'); // or zh-tw
    $('span[moment-format]').each(function(index, element) {
        if($(this).attr('date'))
        {
            $(this).html(
                moment().format($(this).attr('moment-format'))
            );
        }
    });
```